# Snake game - Getting collision to work with images

Tags: c#

This works when I used a rectangle as the food but now I'm trying to use my own image for the food but can't get it to work correctly. I keep getting the error of "Cannot convert Image to Rectangle" when using `IntersectsWith` so I'm stuck there and not sure what to do.

My error is on this part of the code:`if (snake.SnakeRec[i].IntersectsWith(food.foodRec))`

```
for (int i = 0; i < snake.SnakeRec.Length; i++)
        {
            if (snake.SnakeRec[i].IntersectsWith(food.foodRec))
            {
                score += 10;
                snake.growSnake();
                food.foodLocation(randFood);
            }
        } 
        collision();

        this.Invalidate();
```

In the Food.cs class

```
public void drawFood(Graphics paper)
    {
        Image foodRec = Image.FromFile(@"C:\food.bmp"); 
        Rectangle rectangleAreaToDrawImage = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

        paper.DrawImage(foodRec, rectangleAreaToDrawImage);
    }
```

If you need more code let me know.

Edit: Solved

I had to change:

`if (snake.SnakeRec[i].IntersectsWith(food.foodRec))`

`Rectangle rectangleAreaToDrawImage = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);`

to:

`if (snake.SnakeRec[i].IntersectsWith(food.rectangleAreaToDrawImage))`

`rectangleAreaToDrawImage = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending the image into `IntersectsWith` you need to send the images rectangle, like so:

```
// Instead of this:
if (snake.SnakeRec[i].IntersectsWith(food.foodRec))
// Put this:
if (snake.SnakeRec[i].IntersectsWith(food.rectangleAreaToDrawImage))
```

I'm assuming `rectangleAreaToDrawImage` is publicly available because you are using `foodRec` which is in the same class.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I thought that would have fixed it as well, but the snake goes right over the food like it isn't even there.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure that rectangleAreaToDrawImage has some value when you access it from food?

Comment: I have under `public class Food{}` `public Rectangle rectangleAreaToDrawImage;` which I believe is right.

Comment: Got it now, thank you, this was somewhat part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You code as it is now defines foodRec as an image and not a rectangle. Try defining foodRec as a rectangle with the dimensions of your image.